# Not able to apply sort imports rule on CRA

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I am trying eslint to warn for properly sorted imports on CRA.

This is my config, I can't seem to make it work.

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "sort-imports": "warn"
    }
  }
```